# What tests are used to see if there is a statistically significant improvement in the pre post intervention study?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, likert

Conducted a survey (pre and post) on four questions using Likert scale. Based on the number of responses for agree and strongly agree pre and post intervention, computed the relative improvement. I want to know if this relative improvement is statistically significant or not. What test should I do?

Comment: Whether or not your pre and post scores are significantly different, without a control group, your inferences regarding the causal relationship of your intervention are more or less meaningless without a control group not receiving the intervention. The test is also different depending on whether there is a control group or not. Can you clarify (1) whether you have a control group, and (2) whether the control group is matched to, or independent of the intervention group?

Answer (score 3):

A simple test for changes in paired samples is the [Wilcoxon signed-rank test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test). It's nonparametric, so Likert data won't be a problem. You can use this on each item if you like (and correct for [familywise error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familywise_error_rate) inflation if appropriate), or if your items are all supposed to measure the same construct, you can adopt [classical test theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_test_theory) assumptions and sum or average them...*or* you could estimate factor scores using a [rating scale model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytomous_Rasch_model). This is an [item response theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Item_response_theory) approach that produces index scores as continuous data, which might then permit a paired-samples *t*-test as well. However, there's no guarantee that these factor scores would be normally distributed, and the whole process may take a fair amount of data. There are also bootstrap and Bayesian methods for these analyses, though I'm less familiar with them.